# UTF-8 in decimal

Tags: encoding, utf-8, decoding

Is representing UTF-8 encoding in decimals even possible? I think only values till 255 would be correct, am I right?
As far as I know, we can only represent UTF-8 in hex or binary form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is possible. Let's look at an example:

The Unicode code point for ∫ is U+222B.

Its UTF-8 encoding is `E2` `88` `AB`, in hexadecimal representation. In octal, this would be `342` `210` `253`. In decimal, it would be `226` `136` `171`. That is, if you represent each byte separately.

If you look at the same 3 bytes as a single number, you have `E288AB` in hexadecimal; `70504253` in octal; and `14846123` in decimal.